# Como converter mascara monetária em php

Tags: php, number-format

Tenho o seguinte valor em reais "513.40" desejo que este valor fique por inteiro exemplo 513.40000 com todos os arredondamentos, como posso fazer isso ?

Comment: Você diz converter uma string em um float? Se sim, use `floatval`: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.floatval.php

Answer (score 0):

no PHP existe a função [money_format()](http://php.net/money_format) que pode ser usada assim:

```
echo money_format('%.2n', 12345.67);
```

`money_format` sempre começa com `%`. O `.2` indica que você quer sempre usar duas casas decimais. Se você passar um número inteiro, ele adicionará 0,00 ao final. O `n` indica que você deseja usar o formato de moeda nacional do local.

É importante observar que você deve definir a localidade corretamente, já que `money_format` é baseado na localidade que você definiu para `LC_MONETARY`. Para definir o local, use `setlocale`. Nesse caso, parece que você quer pt_BR.

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'pt_BR');
```